# import the .csv with space and special character in between the variables in to SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I have datasets in .CSV contains more then 50 Variables with space and / within variables. I have to import with infile statement becouse I cant do it by proc import. What is the best way to deal this kind of data either to mask or rename it. On top of that I have to work with these variables further. Please find the sample data below.

The Variable names are:
Engne Serial Number
Event Year
Most Recent Record Indicator By Module
Registration/Tail Number

```
Engine Serial Number, Event Year, Most Recent Record Indicator By Module, Registration/Tail Number
1245,1995,2,AK251
```

Comment: Have you tried the import wizard in SAS Enterprise Guide?  It can convert these for you, besides a lot of other nice features.

Comment: Is it only the variable names that have spaces or the data itself? Also, how come there are no commas in a CSV file? Perhaps you mean space or tab delimited?

Comment: @Aniko: The space is only in the variables and yes there is commas becoz of .csv

Comment: @Jeff: I can do it by menu driven but there are 10 more files, So, I dont want to use menu driven. I need to work further on these variables, My question is how can i import and work going forward with space and special character.

Comment: `PROC IMPORT` or a regular data step read-in should treat spaces like any other character.  It will convert the variable name spaces to underscores (if you use proc import) or you can name the variables whatever you want (in data step).